# Framework7 + AngularJS (DOM changes so angular can't find controllers)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, html-framework-7

I'm using framework7 and AngularJS for making a mobile app. I just need AngularJS for databinding.

When clicking on a link with framework7, the content of a div changes. In the new content I set a new controller, but angular can't find it. Is there a way to notify angular that the DOM has changed?

You can download the project here: http://www35.zippyshare.com/v/yDszXHuB/file.html

This DemoController in index.html works. It changes the {{title}}

[image]

This DemoControllerAbout in about.html does not work. It won't change {{title}}

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you minify your running js code? if yes, your controller name might get minified too...

Comment: no, I'm not minifying my code. I think the controller can't be found because it's not in the DOM when angularjs gets loaded.

Comment: check maybe you are placing your script src=app.js after script src=angularjs.  it shouldnt matter   but try.

Comment: script src=app.js IS loaded after script src=angularjs.

Comment: try change that... load your controllers first   then angular?

Comment: I think that's not possible. Angular is not defined when I put app.js above angular.js.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the integration of Framework7 and AngularJS is a work-in-progress.  Specifically, page routing functionality conflicts with each other leading to undesired effects.

See https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

You should try to compile the views on pageinit event. Try this

```
Framework7.prototype.plugins.angular = function(app, params) {
    function compile(newPage) {
        try {
            var $page = $(newPage);
            var injector = angular.element("[ng-app]").injector();
            var $compile = injector.get("$compile");
            var $timeout = injector.get("$timeout");
            var $scope = injector.get("$rootScope");
            $scope = $scope.$$childHead;
            $timeout(function() {
                $compile($page)($scope);
            })
        } catch (e) {
            //console.error("Some Error Occured While Compiling The Template", e);
        }
    }

    return {
        hooks: {
            pageInit: function(pageData) {
                compile(pageData.container);
            }
        }
    }

};
```

and set this plugin while initialization of framework7 app

```
new Framework7({
  ....
  angular : true
  ....
})
```

For more details you can refer below github repo with fully working demos
https://github.com/ashvin777/framework7.angular

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile the DOM snippet that's being injected:

```
$compile(domSnippet)($scope);
$scope.$apply();
```

See more info on this blog article I created: http://www.timo-ernst.net/blog/2016/02/24/how-to-use-ajax-pages-with-angular-1-x-in-framework7/

There is also a demo project available on Github: https://github.com/valnub/Framework7-Ajax-Pages-With-Angular-Demo